# What is the most efficient way to display a 2d array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

After some trial and errors I am now able to display the 2d array as I want, except I do not want a line break intitially before the first array item.

I want my output to look like this:

```
123
456
789
```

But it looks like this:

```
(blank line)
123
456
789
```

My JavaScript code:

```js
x = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

i = 0;
while (i < x.length) {
  j = 0;
  while (j < x.length) {
    if (j % 3 === 0) {
      document.write('<br/>' + x[i][j]);
    } else {
      document.write(x[i][j]);
    }
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how display efficiency has anything to do with removing a `<br>`

Comment: well do not append one on the first iteration.... seems like a simple addition to the if....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the inner loop and use `join()` to merge the sub array elements into string

Add the `<br>` when `i` is not zero

```js
var x = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

var i = -1;
while (++i < x.length) {
  document.write( (i>0 ? '<br/>' : '') + x[i].join(''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
x = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

i = 0;
while (i < x.length) {
  j = 0;
  while (j < x.length) {
    if (j % 3 === 0) {
      if (i != 0) {
          document.write('<br/>');
      }
      document.write(x[i][j]);
    } else {
      document.write(x[i][j]);
    }
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: that is less efficient with two ifs ;)

Comment: I want to know if there is a more elegant way instead of having to check on first iteration to not append <br/>

Comment: :D You can check if it's the last element. But this is an extra piece of information you need to get it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the line break in the outer loop with a check and take only the value inside the innner loop.

The inserted condition

```
if (i) {
```

checks the variable `i` for [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)ness and takes in this case the value unequal to zero as `true` value and skips the line break for the first line.

BTW, it is a good idea to declare variables - in advance.

```js
var x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    i = 0,
    j;

while (i < x.length) {
    j = 0;
    if (i) {
        document.write('<br/>');
    }
    while (j < x[i].length) {    // take the inner array for length
        document.write(x[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

A shorter approach with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
var x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

document.write(x.map(a => a.join('')).join('<br>'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I don't under stand how the if(i) works though

Comment: See [my aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47998477/6577822) you do not need any if statements.

Comment: @fjoe, you move the problem of the superfluous line break to the end.

Comment: I like the map and join :) and that handles the extra line break. Although personally I would want the extra line break in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to rethink your logic.

You always want to print the current value. So I removed the logic around that.
You want to print a new line when the current array is ending.

If you structure it right you do not need any if statements.

See code below:

```js
x = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

i = 0;
while (i < x.length) {
  j = 0;
  while (j < x[i].length) {
    document.write(x[i][j]);
    j++;
  }
  document.write('<br/>');
  i++;
}
```